# MySQL update with multiple where

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a query in which i can update a field , with certain where clauses which reside in different tables

To make sure that i do not update all fields which represent the id  i need another where clause which also checks if a `service_name like '%DISK%'` exists in table service_members:

However this results in (logically):

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'service_members' for update in FROM clause
```

My best try so far:

My initial query is not stringent enough as it matches an id/hostname , this id is present multiple times:

```
update service_members 
set check_command_data = replace(check_command_data,'80%!90%','90%!95%') 
where host_name in (select id from host where host_name like '%server-01%');
```

Output:

```
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Rows matched: 23  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0
```

It works of course but will update the 'new value' which matches on the same 'old value'

What i need to realize in one query:

- update in table service_members setting new value for field
  check_command_data (works)
- host_name needs to be a select id from table host where the host_name
  is like %something% (works but not stringent enough)
- service_name in table service_members needs to be a select like %DISK%

I'm a bit puzzled on how to get this query working in the right way , any advice/suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide the piece of code that gives the error you have shown please?

Comment: update service_members set check_command_data=replace(check_command_data,'80%!90%','90%!95%') where host_name in (select id from service_members where host_name = '3389' and service_name like '%MEMORY%');
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'service_members' for update in FROM clause

This ofcourse makes sense... cannot update and select from same table

Comment: the query how i think it would look like , but still has errors:
update service_members where service_name like '%DISK%' set check_command_data=replace(check_command_data,'c:!10%!5%','c:!5%!2%') where host_name in (select id from host where host_name like '%server-01%');

Comment: You can use the following query-

    `UPDATE service_members
    SET check_command_data = replace(check_command_data,'80%!90%','90%!95%')
    WHERE host_name IN (SELECT id FROM host WHERE host_name LIKE '%server-01%')
    AND service_name like '%DISK%'`

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, that would do the trick is suppose :)